# How can I transfer files between Samsung Galaxy Note 800 and usb pen drive?

Tags: file-transfer

Is it compulsory that I need a Desktop or Laptop to transfer files between Samsung Galaxy 800 and a usb pen drive.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are other ways to copy files from a USB pen drive to a phone.

According to [USB Host Diagnostics](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/?search=n8000), the N8000 can support the USB OTG (on-the-go) cable, assuming you have the latest firmware. Just plug-in the USB pen drive (or USB stick) into it. This cable will cost you USD1 or less.

If you have root, you can use [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=en) to make the mounting of the USB pen drive easier.